# Improve scrolling performance of phonegap app in android

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework

I'm working an mobile application built using ionic, angular and cordova. I've a list with 500 items and the scrolling is bad in Samsung Note I. I know 500 is a little big number but I'm curious to know is there any means to improve the performance.

Here is the code,

```
<ion-list show-delete="showDelete"> 
      <ion-item ng-repeat="user in users" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/tab/user/{{user.id}}" class="item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right">
        <img src="{{user.image}}">
        <h2>{{user.name}}</h2>
        <p>{{user.role}}</p>
        <i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-right"></i>
        <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled" ng-click="delete(user)">
        </ion-delete-button>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

Comment: In my experience, performance is something that you trade off for the productivity offered by using Cordova+Angular.I used that combination a year ago when we did our tests for our product.We ended up using JQuery mobile to create UI virtualization instead of using Angular. NOTE: We did not use ionic.

Comment: If you are just starting up on your project and you have strict performance requirements, I would suggest giving Xamarin a look if you are comfortable with C# or try a native solution. Note that lists with 500 items should really be no problem with PhoneGap anyway if you implement UI virtualization and re-use 4-5 screens worth of items.

Comment: Xamarin is not free and I can't go with that. May be I can try UI virtualization in Phonegap.

Comment: The idea is basically to reuse list items. Simply reposition them once they fall well outside of the view and set the data manually. We used to have 100 live list items this way with no problem in scrolling whatsoever.

Comment: Interesting! can you please the complete idea as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I'll check and find the source code we used and paste it as an answer as soon as possible.

Comment: I have been used Phonegap to build apps. In Android, large list is very poor performance when scrolling. I think you should use lazy load for your list. Only show minimal element at the same time to have best performance.

Comment: Why you must show 500 items at the same time when user only view + interact with 10 items in the screen?.

Comment: @HanhLe I want to create the feeling to the user that all the 500 records are displayed in the screen. In reality, I'll display only 10 items when they scroll, I'll display additional items. But I want to fake the height of the scrollbar to make the user feel all the records are displayed.

Comment: @Mark i think your list very large, it will make device slow down performance. I not have any solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The secret to performant large lists is in reusing DOM elements. You may have 500 items, but only 10 are on on the screen at the same time. So, we can save a lot of memory and CPU time by recycling elements as they go off the screen.

Ionic comes with a directive that does exactly this - [**check it out.**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/collectionRepeat/)